# C++ Forward Declaration and Inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, visitor-pattern

I have a situation as such

A.h

```
#ifndef _CLASSA
#define _CLASSA
class B;

class A {
    virtual void addTo(B*) {}
};

#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef _CLASSB
#define _CLASSB

#include "A.h"

class B : public A {
    B();
    void addTo(B* b) {
         // blah blah blah
    }
};

#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

B::B() : A() {}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

int main() {
    A* b = new B();
    B* d = new B();
    b->addTo(d);
}
```

The project won't compile.  If I forward declare B in the A header, the compiler complains about the expectation of a class in B.h.  If I include the B.h header in A.h, the compiler can't resolve the base class.  Is this possible?

Comment: Does your real code also leave out the `;` after each class definition, and have a rogue `class` in the inheritance list? Both of these syntax errors will prevent it compiling.

Comment: In general, you'll get better answers if you include (a) some real code that we can put into a compiler to reproduce the problem, and (b) the exact error(s) you're getting.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing a little fast.  I'ts fixed up now.

Comment: So what exactly is the error? The code you've posted compiles for me: http://ideone.com/rbzBp.

Comment: Completed the code.  Undefined reference to vtable for A

Comment: could it be that you are calling private methods of `B`?

Comment: That probably means that you declared a non-pure virtual function, but didn't implement it. Check that all the virtual functions are either pure (with a `=0` after them), or have an implementation. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1693787/204847).

Comment: I wrote up this http://ideone.com/z3i6z and it seems to work... Now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: In my real project, the include patters were extremely dirty.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular dependencies of declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748624/circular-dependencies-of-declarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, include `A.h` in `B.h` and forward declare `B` in `A.h`.

> If I forward declare B in the A header, the compiler complains about the expectation of a class in B.h

The way you have the code now it should work. But I suspect you're actually using `B` inside the method `addTo`, in which case a forward declaration is not enough. You need to separate the implementation to an implementation file and include `B` there.

EDIT: As DeadMg pointed out, `class B : class A {` isn't valid syntax, you probably want `class B : A` or `class B : public A`.

Comment: You're missing the fact that he has `: class A`, which is a syntax error